# Is there any way to find location with in radius in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, geolocation

How can I find radious based Location based on one point latitude and longitude and given radius.
Suppose, I have given 30 as Radius than it will find result of that particular given latitude and longitude with in the 30 radius.
I have tried below code:

```
    $lat = '37.421998'; // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
    $lon = '-122.084000'; // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
    $rad = 30; // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

    $R = 6371;  // earth's mean radius, km

    // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
    $maxLat = $lat + rad2deg($rad/$R);
    $minLat = $lat - rad2deg($rad/$R);
    $maxLon = $lon + rad2deg(asin($rad/$R) / cos(deg2rad($lat)));
    $minLon = $lon - rad2deg(asin($rad/$R) / cos(deg2rad($lat)));

   $results = DB::select('Select id, latitude, longitude, acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-(:lon))) * (:R) As D From ( Select id, latitude, longitude From jobs_master Where latitude Between (:minLat) And (:maxLat) And longitude Between (:minLon) And (:maxLon) ) As FirstCut Where acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(:lat)*cos( radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-(:lon))) * :R < :rad ', ['maxLat' => $maxLat,'maxLon' => $maxLon, 'minLat' => $minLat,'minLon' => $minLon, 'lat' => $lat,'lon' => $lon,'R'=> $R,'rad'=>$rad]);

        dd(DB::getQueryLog());exit;
        print_r($results);exit;
```

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a nice solution for your problems with Laravel using Eloquent Query, This method is written for different scenario but exactly what you are looking for:

```
private function findNearestRestaurants($latitude, $longitude, $radius = 400)
    {
        /*
         * using eloquent approach, make sure to replace the "Restaurant" with your actual model name
         * replace 6371000 with 6371 for kilometer and 3956 for miles
         */
        $restaurants = Restaurant::selectRaw("id, name, address, latitude, longitude, rating, zone ,
                         ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( latitude ) )
                           * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                         ) AS distance", [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
            ->orderBy("distance",'asc')
            ->offset(0)
            ->limit(20)
            ->get();

        return $restaurants;
    }
```

Reference: https://www.techalyst.com/posts/laravel-find-nearest-restaurants-from-certain-gps-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following calculation and modify query according to your needs:

```
$query = "SELECT (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $latitude - latitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS( $latitude * pi()/180) * COS(latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $longitude - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance, latitude, longitude" FROM TABLES HAVING distance <= 30
```

So in the above query we first calculate the distance by given latitude & longitude and then use HAVING clause by to limit the distance to 30 km radius.

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: I didn't have stored distance field into database. In table latitude and longitude is only there.

Comment: what is 3956 in above answer let me know so i will try with it?

Comment: Thanks It works for me in sql environment but In laravel structure it's not work !..

Comment: You don't need distance field in your table. The distance here is actually the alias of the calculation performed in the sql.

Comment: You can always write manual queries in laravel using DB facade i.e. query builder. For your reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries

Comment: The number 3956 is used to calculate the distance in miles